# chartjs maintain points position, put image alongside with label

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am struggling with charjs. I do not know how exactly I can maintain the positions of the points. And also I would like to put an image alongside with label (The way I wanna see it you can see in the picture). I will appreciate any help.
[image]

Below you can see my code. As you can see I've used datalabels plugin to show label inside of the points.
Do not get confused of detailed consitions. Depends on condition I am visualising a slightly different graphs.

```
  <div>
    <canvas id="dh"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
import 'chartjs-plugin-dragdata'
import 'chartjs-chart-graph'
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'

//const data = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-graph/master/samples/tree.json`
let clickCount = 0
let singleClickTimer

export default {
  name: 'CDiagramChart',
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    },
    detailed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let images = []
    this.data.forEach(element => {
      this.$logger.log(element)
      images.push('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RAv2.png')
    })
    this.$logger.log(images)
    function createChart(nodes, id, type, orientation, detailed) {
      if (detailed) {
        new Chart(document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d'), {
          type,
          data: {
            labels: nodes.map(d => d.name),
            datasets: [
              {
                borderWidth: 1,
                lineTension: 0,
                borderColor: 'steelblue',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'orange',
                pointRadius: 50,
                pointHoverRadius: 50,
                pointStyle: 'rect',
                data: nodes.map(d => Object.assign({}, d))
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            dragData: true,
            dragX: true,
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    min: -1,
                    max: 2,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    fixedStepSize: 1
                  }
                }
              ],
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    min: -2,
                    max: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    fixedStepSize: 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true,
              intersect: false
            },
            tree: {
              orientation
            },
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            layout: {
              padding: {
                top: 0,
                left: 50,
                right: 50,
                bottom: 0
              }
            },
            plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                display: true,
                align: orientation === 'vertical' ? 'bottom' : 'center',
                font: {
                  size: 16,
                  family: 'Arial'
                },
                formatter: v => {
                  return v.name
                }
              }
            },
            onClick: function(event, dataAtClick) {
              clickCount++
              if (clickCount === 1) {
                singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                  clickCount = 0
                  console.log('Single Click', dataAtClick[0]?._index)
                }, 400)
              } else if (clickCount === 2) {
                clearTimeout(singleClickTimer)
                clickCount = 0
                console.log('Double Click', dataAtClick[0]?._index)
              }
            }
          }
        })
      } else {
        new Chart(document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d'), {
          type,
          data: {
            labels: nodes.map(d => d.name),
            datasets: [
              {
                borderWidth: 1,
                lineTension: 0,
                borderColor: 'steelblue',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'orange',
                pointRadius: 50,
                pointHoverRadius: 50,
                pointStyle: 'rect',
                data: nodes.map(d => Object.assign({}, d))
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            dragData: false,
            dragX: false,
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    min: -1,
                    max: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    fixedStepSize: 1
                  }
                }
              ],
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    min: -1,
                    max: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    fixedStepSize: 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true,
              intersect: false
            },
            tree: {
              orientation
            },
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            layout: {
              padding: {
                top: 0,
                left: 50,
                right: 50,
                bottom: 0
              }
            },
            plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                display: true,
                align: orientation === 'vertical' ? 'bottom' : 'center',
                font: {
                  size: 16,
                  family: 'Arial'
                },
                formatter: v => {
                  return v.name
                }
              }
            },
            onClick: function(event, dataAtClick) {
              clickCount++
              if (clickCount === 1) {
                singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                  clickCount = 0
                  console.log('Single Click', dataAtClick[0]?._index)
                }, 400)
              } else if (clickCount === 2) {
                clearTimeout(singleClickTimer)
                clickCount = 0
                console.log('Double Click', dataAtClick[0]?._index)
              }
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
    createChart(this.data, 'dh', 'dendogram', 'horizontal', this.detailed)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding position correction. I used tree as a type instead of dendogram and it worked perfectly `this.createChart(this.dataTest, 'dh', 'tree', 'horizontal', this.detailed)`. The question about image remains the same